# How to have a list of memory views in Cython?

Tags: python, cython, memoryview

My function takes in a list of differently sized numpy arrays:

`def function1(list list_of_numpy_arrays):`

Right now I am doing:

`cdef int[:] a_view = list_of_numpy_arrays[index]`

The problem is I have to index the list a large number of times so the overhead greatly increases the time (10x). I am looking for something like `cdef int[:] a[5]` where I can have an array of memory views so I can avoid the overhead of indexing python lists.

I am also able to pass in a list of lists if there is a solution for that.

`def function2(list list_of_lists):`

Comment: Some potential questions to consider. 1) Are there a fixed or maximum number of numpy arrays that can be in the list? 2) Is it possible to make all of the numpy arrays have the same shape, or is the memory waste that would result too much? 3) Do the arrays need to be accessible as numpy arrays in python, or is the data only being processed on the cython-side after that call to `function1`? 4) Do you need to be able in use `[]` syntax to get each numpy array, or is a function call sufficient?

Comment: 1) I can make the maximum number to be 20, but it can be less. 2) Each array would be half the size of the previous. 3) I don't have to index the arrays in Python, but a reference to them is needed to call them again in Cython. 4) I am not sure what you mean, but I will need to get each numpy array by index.

Comment: If you have predictable array sizes like that (each half the size of the previous), I'd consider using a big 1d array for the whole thing and just calculating the start point in it for each "sub array" - that would probably make more sense than my answer...

Comment: True, that does make more sense. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're after isn't really possible in Cython. If you want something that performs well I'd probably create a C struct that contains the relevant information from the memoryview and then use that instead. This isn't a very elegant solution but it will give similar performance to using memoryviews; I wouldn't recommend making it a common pattern but if you have a one-off problem where your data requires in then it's OK.

```
cdef struct FakeMemoryView:
    int* data
    int stride
    int length
```

If you were prepared to force C contiguous memorviews (`int[::1]`) then you could ditch `stride` since it would be known to be one. Data can be indexed using `var.data[i*var.stride]`. At the start of your function you loop through your Python list to create an array of these `FakeMemoryView`s, then from that point on you just use this array:

```
def function1(list list_of_numpy_arrays):
    assert len(list_of_numpy_arrays) == 5

    cdef FakeMemoryView new_list[5]

    # initialize the list
    cdef int[:] mview
    for i in range(5):
        mview = list_of_numpy_arrays[i]
        new_list[i].data = &mview[0]
        new_list[i].stride = mview.strides[0]
        new_list[i].length = mview.shape[0]

    # example access - zero the first lot of data
    for i in range(new_list[0].length):
        new_list[0].data[i*new_list[0].stride] = 0
```

If you don't know the length of the list in advance then you need to handle the memory for it yourself with `malloc` and `free`.

This solution does not handle reference-counting the Numpy arrays - therefore you should not allow the Numpy arrays to be deallocated while holding `FakeMemoryView`s. Don't store your array for more than a single function call, and don't start dropping arrays from the input list.